# Use Silverlight 3 to Open Word Document

Tags: silverlight, ms-word, silverlight-3.0, ms-office

I have a requirement to open a Microsoft Word document using Silverlight 3.

The Word document will be populated from a web service. Can anyone please point me in the right direction on how to achieve this? I could also open it as a .pdf if that would be easier. I can't use any 3rd party tools either, as they have to go through lengthy due diligence process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silverlight has really limited access to the end users system.  I would recommend making a call to a WCF service to build the file, then send the bytes down to the client.  The Silverlight app would then use the `SaveFileDialog` to allow the user to save the file to their system.

This will not open the file automatically.  Is there a specific reason you have to open the file?

Comment: Thanks, that's sounding like it may not be as painful as anticipated. Yeah it's a report that the users run, and in the previous access system, the report opens when u click on a link. I might be able to get away with prompting the user to save it. Still can't figure out how to open the created file.

Comment: You have no way of launching a program on the end users computer with Silverlight.  Maybe Out Of Browser, but I don't have any experience there.

Comment: you've still prompted me in the right direction...i'll give feedback when i implement it and will mark it accordingly if it works....thanks for your comments.

Comment: Thanks for prompting me in the right direction, it worked well, using the SaveFleDialog and then using the WCF service to create the file on the filesystem. I had to do some heavy lifting in certain places which was specific to my application, but this is definately the right direction for Silverlight 3 application.